# Iframe position absolute not working in android browser

Tags: android, iframe, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, android-browser

I have a simple web page with an iframe inside a `div` container.
Used bootstrap responsive every thing works fine with the below code:

```
  <div id="container">
     <iframe id="iframe2"  name="iframe2"  
     style="position:absolute;top:60px;bottom:0px;height:80%;" width="100%"
         frameborder="0"  src="../dashboard_portal.jsp">
   </iframe>            
  </div>
```

Above code works fine in chromium ,IE, Firefox without any issues.
When i try to open the page from android mobile.. this attribute `position:absolute;` is causing issues in dispalying the iframe.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I came up with some ugly workaround, anyone can suggest for better :)

I have wrapped the `Iframe` inside a `div` container with `position:fixed` & `z-index:-999`

```
 <div id="container" style="position: fixed;top:60px;bottom:0px;height:80%;width: 100%;z-
 index: -999;border: 0" >
      <iframe id="iframe2"  name="iframe2" width="100%" height="100%" style="" 
       frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
      </iframe>         
</div>
```

Thanks.